# how can make editing page, and update file with multiple file upload like Filepond?

Tags: laravel, filepond

I use Filepond to upload product images in Laravel.
But I have problem in show product multiple image editing page.
how can I show Previous image in editing page with filepond and use its for update if user don't edit?

I can show Previous image in editing page but I can't use it again for update form.